# Easiest way to list entity class field-level deltas between last saved and new

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have a requirement by which I have to detect and save field-level deltas between the last saved and new changes of an entity class, which is modified through a `JSF` front end.  IOW, the form, entity class, and the DB table may have X number of fields and on every save, anywhere between 0 and X can be changed.  I need to find on every save all the ones that have changes and log them somewhere for audit purposes.

At first I thought of modifying each setter:

```
@Transient
private Set<String> changes;

...

public void setSomeField(String _newval) {

    if(!_newval.equals(this.someField)){
        this.changes.add("SOME_FIELD");
    }

    this.someField = _newval;
}
```

which would require this non-elegant delta detection logic to be implemented in each setter and I don't like it.  Is there an easy way to diff the new state from the persisted state using some `JPA` function that would give me a listing of all the fields changes and that I can then dump into my audit log storage?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect fit an interceptor in combination with an annotation.  Create one, annotate the entity (classlevel would be great, but method level (setters) would be acceptible I think) and all work is done automagically. What and when you do log the results is up to you, but that could be in an entitylistener.

But why not use [Envers](http://envers.jboss.org/) it does excately all this (afaik jpa implementation independent)

Comment: can you provide some code samples how this should be done?  i have not used interceptors before (I'm assuming it is something like an aspect)

Comment: Yes, it is 'like aspects'.  But I edited my answer with a reference to what I once wanted to use.  And an example (a lot more than one)  of how to create interceptors can be via google (bet stackoverflow has some to)

Comment: Small introductory example of a modern interceptor http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-cdi-interceptor/README.htm

Comment: Must it be generic jpa?